# Remove one Windows version in UEFI boot if 2 are presents

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, uefi, bootloader

While I was installing Windows 10 on my PC I have partitioned the HDD in 2 parts: the first for the OS, the second for data. Unfortunatelly during the installation I have made a mistake so I have installed the OS on the second partition. Subsequently I have restarted the system, formatted the second partition and installed Windows10 on the first partition.

Now when I boot the system, the UEFI boot ask me which partition start (notice that 1st partition has the OS, 2nd partition is empty), selecting the first the OS starts, selecting the second the loading stops and restart the machine.

I would like to say: how to remove the second choice in the UEFI menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "msconfig" and go to the "Boot" tab. From there you can delete your boot options.

[image: msconfig]